# Rails 4 - Create route functions in a generic template for many different resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 tables for 2 different resources:

**Customers:**

```
<table class="va-table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4">Name</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Surname</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= link_to customer["name"], customer %></td>
                <td><%= link_to customer["surname"], customer %></td>
                <td>
                    <%= render 'button/button', { type: "primary", text: "Edit", link: edit_customer_path(customer), classes: "btn-sm" } %>
                    <%= render 'button/button', { type: "danger", text: "Delete", link: customer, classes: "btn-sm", parameters: { method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } } } %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Services:**

```
<table class="va-table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Price</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Duration</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <% @services.each do |service| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= link_to service.name, service %></td>
                <td><%= link_to service.price.to_s + " €", service %></td>
                <td><%= link_to service.duration.to_s + " minutes", service %></td>
                <td>
                    <%= render 'button/button', { type: "primary", text: "Edit", link: edit_service_path(service), classes: "btn-sm" } %>
                    <%= render 'button/button', { type: "danger", text: "Delete", link: service, classes: "btn-sm", parameters: { method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } } } %>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Since they are so similar, I thought: "Let's be cool and refactor". And this is what I came up with:

```
<%
# Default values
data ||= {}
fields ||= []

sample = data.sample
%>

<table class="va-table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <% fields.each do |field| %>
                <th class="col-md-4"><%= sample.class.human_attribute_name(field) %></th>
            <% end %>
            <th class="col-md-4">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <% data.each do |data| %>
            <tr>
                <% fields.each do |field| %>
                    <td><%= link_to data[field], data %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td>
                    ????? WHAT HERE ?????
                    <%= render 'button/button', { type: "danger", text: "Delete", link: data, classes: "btn-sm", parameters: { method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } } } %>

                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem I have found is, how do I create the proper link targets, for the "Edit" action?

Comment: create your own helper for edit path, which will accept model name and model object to generate edit link. This should be with assumption model and controller name will be same just pluralization is required.

Comment: I don't really agree with the full refactoring of the data portion, you're losing information (the currency denomination, the duration unit, etc.). I would personally create single data partials and render the relevant one based on the class of the data.

Comment: I was simplifying the refactoring. That information will be kept with further tuning ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send).

`send("edit_#{sample.class}_path", args)`

Or alternatively define a view helper to generate the different links based on your `sample.class`